# How do I take a list of strings and count them while ommitting empty lines?

Tags: python, string, list, function

```
def count_lines(lst):
    """ (list of str) -> int

    Precondition: each str in lst[:-1] ends in \n.

    Return the number of non-blank, non-empty strings in lst.

    >>> count_lines(['The first line leads off,\n', '\n', '  \n',
    ... 'With a gap before the next.\n', 'Then the poem ends.\n'])
    3
    """
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this;

```
def count_lines(lst):
   return sum(1 for line in lst if line.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

[`str.isspace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) will tell you if a string is all whitespace characters.  So, you can use `sum` and count how many items in `lst` return `True` for `not item.isspace()`:

```
>>> def count_lines(lst):
...     return sum(not x.isspace() for x in lst)
...
>>> count_lines(['The first line leads off,\n', '\n', '  \n', 'With a gap before the next.\n', 'Then the poem ends.\n'])
3
>>>
```